# MediaPlayer - setDataSource failing - Couldn't open fd for content://

Tags: android

My app downloads audio files to `/sdcard/Music`. When I try to play them, I am getting the following error.

> V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 2789): setDataSource: path
>   content://media/external/audio/med ia/2 E/MediaPlayerService( 1130):
>   Couldn't open fd for content://media/external/audio /media/2

If I download the files to `/sdcard/` instead, the files play fine. The program creates the sub folder 'Music'  just before download and the permissions for 'sdcard' and 'Music' look same.

Comment: I have the same problem, just wondering if you finally found a solution

Comment: Obviously a way late answer, but I noticed there's a space in the content URIs.  That may be the problem.